# How to implement .map() using for()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have these array and variable:

```
var arr      = [['one','blue'], ['two','red'], ['three','green']]   
var variable = 'thre';
```

Also I have this code:

```
arr.map(function(x){ 
    if(x[0].indexOf(variable) >= 0)
    {
        alert('Number is found');
    }
});
```

As you know, `map` works as a loop, and in the array above, there is three items and then `map` executes its statement 3 times. So that `alert` will be run.

---

Now I'm trying to limit the mapping, I mean I want to execute a statement 2 times. So I user `for()` like this:

```
for ( var c = 0; c < 2; c++ ) {
    if ( arr[c][0].indexOf(variable) >= 0 )
    {
        alert('number is found');
    }
}
```

But ^ doesn't work, It gives me this error:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property '0' of undefined {in line 2}

How can I fix it?

---

**EDIT:** Here is my code in reality:

```
    ZippedArray.map(function(x){
                    if(x[0].indexOf(name) >= 0)
                    {
                        MatchesNames.push(x[0]);
                        MatchesIds.push(x[1]);
                    }
                });
```

I want this output:

```
MatchesNames = MatchesNames.slice(0,2);
MatchesIds   = MatchesIds.slice(0,2);
```

How to limit `.map()` ? I want something like `break;` after 2 times.

Comment: `arr[0]` is undefined, which means you can't access its 0th property, because it has none. Debug it to find out why that is. It's hard for us to say since you're giving incomplete code. Apparently `arr` is empty. Is this your intention?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ok well, may you please tell me how can I limit the `.map` function?

Comment: Your code does not produce that error. But if you're saying you want to limit the iterations of `.map()`, take a `.slice()` of the array. Like `arr.slice(0, 2).map(...`

Comment: ...however, I don't know why you're using `.map()` in that example, since you don't seem to be using the resulting array. You sure you didn't mean `.forEach()`? Or maybe you're trying to find an index, so maybe `.findIndex()`?

Comment: I see. Then `.slice()` should have you covered.

Comment: @squint Oh shit :-( .. that `.slice()` it doesn't fine me, lemme update my question

Comment: Do you want to limit or do you want to loop only until the first match?

Comment: I don't know why slice wouldn't work. And your updated code still doesn't use the resulting array from `.map()`. Seems like you're building two different arrays, so `.forEach()` would make more sense there.

Comment: @squint `slice()` limits the main array, but I want to limit result arrays ..

Comment: @Shafizadeh: By limiting the main array, it would seem that you will be limiting the resulting arrays. Unless those arrays may already have content in them?

Comment: ...oh, do you want to always push up to 2 items?

Comment: Then use `.some()`, and do `return true;` after you've found the second item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems you want to loop until you've found two matches in the `if` condition.

In that case, you can use `.some()`, which will halt the loop as soon as you return `true` (or any truthy value).

```
ZippedArray.some(function(x){
    if(x[0].indexOf(name) >= 0)
    {
        MatchesNames.push(x[0]);
        MatchesIds.push(x[1]);
    }
    return MatchesNames.length == 2; // Breaks when this returns `true`
});
```

This example assumes that `MatchesNames` was empty before you called `.some()`.

---

If there could be other items in the array, and you just want to push two more in at the most, then you could keep a count.

```
var found = 0;

ZippedArray.some(function(x){
    if(x[0].indexOf(name) >= 0)
    {
        MatchesNames.push(x[0]);
        MatchesIds.push(x[1]);
        found++;
    }
    return found == 2;
});
```

---

If you want to use a traditional `for` loop, then do this:

```
var found = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < ZippedArray.length; i++) {
    var x = ZippedArray[i];

    if(x[0].indexOf(name) >= 0)
    {
        MatchesNames.push(x[0]);
        MatchesIds.push(x[1]);
        found++;
    }
    if (found == 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ... this is a good solution .. +1 .. But unfortunately `.some()` doesn't work on old browsers and I try don't use it :(

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Neither does `.map()`. It's easy to patch in any old browser. Otherwise, just use a `for` loop and make the `MachesNames.length` comparison into an `if` statement, and use `break;` when the condition succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted does not throw an error.

But when you're limiting the loop count of iterating an array, you should add a range check for the index:

```
for (var c = 0; c < 2 && c < arr.length; c++) {

// or alternatively

for (var c = 0, l = Math.min(2, arr.length); c < l; c++) {
```

Comment: Yes ... `c < arr.length` removed that error ..! + 1, thank you .. But counting the length of that array every time in the condition is optimize?

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Accessing `arr.lenght` does not count anything, it's `O(1)`. If you want to avoid re-evaluating it every turn, use the second alternative with the `l` variable. Notice that this "optimisation" is not worth the effort, engines are able to do it theirselves.

Comment: As a consult: The most of my website's users use IE8, and `.map()` doesn't support in IE8. Also I have used `.map()` in my codes. What should I do now? *(Note: I use jquery)*

Comment: O you poor guy… Honestly tell them that IE8 is dead and they [should](http://browser-update.org/) [switch to](http://browsehappy.com/) [another](https://browser-update.org/) [browser](https://whatbrowser.org/). If you cannot afford that (but can afford the cost of keeping your page IE8-compatible), you can of course always install the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) in your scripts